# Como imprimir apenas vogais contidas em uma string?

Tags: python

Implemente uma função em Python que receba uma string como parâmetro e imprima as vogais dessa string.

Exemplo:

string `univesp` → deve imprimir os caracteres `'u'`, `'i'` e `'e'`.

Consegui fazer isso aqui, mas não é o que foi pedido.

```
str = ['univesp']

for palavra in str:
    for c in palavra:
        if c in 'aeiou':
            print(c)
```

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou. Você quer printar tudo na mesma linha?

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de imprimir o resultado solicitado você não definiu uma função. Tente:

```
def vogais(str):
    for c in str:
        if c in 'aeiou':
            print(c)

vogais('univesp')
```